# Trying to read list of tuples with date-pairs in bash is failing using argparse

Tags: python, bash, list, tuples, argparse

I have python script that one of its' parameters is list of tuples:

```
def my_func(my_date_list: list=None, #List of dates to be used. Example for list : [('2017-07-02', '2017-08-15'),('2019-09-02', '2019-11-21')]):

...
```

This function works when I run it from my Jupyter notebook.
However when I try to run it on bash, it can't really access the dates correctly.
This is what I did with argparse + bash command:

```
import ast

def parse_args():
    '''Parser for my script '''
    
    parser.add_argument('--date_list',type=str, default=None, required=False,
                        help=f"#List of dates to be used. Example for list : [('2017-07-02', '2017-08-15'),('2019-09-02', '2019-11-21')]")      

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.date_list is not None:
        date_list = ast.literal_eval(args.date_list)
        print(date_list)
```

my bash command:

```
python3 main_func.py --date_list "[('2017-07-02','2020-03-02')]"
#this fails when the script gets to the part where it should worlk with the date
>>>end_date=date_range[LOC_1],
>>>IndexError: string index out of range
```

It's important to mention that **this script does work when running from my Jupyter notebook so I believe problem is with parsing the argument**.
I am looking for solution for how I can use the date list parameter when I run the script from bash.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that initializes `date_range`, which is what the error message actually complains about.

Comment: I think more complete example code would be helpful here. Is that really all there is to your `parse_args` function? You don't return anything.

Comment: I think the problem is with the argparse and not with the other part of the function and that's why I haven't put it here. The function calls a lot of others functions so I think it will be too much information to put on one question here

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you've shared (apart possibly from the fact that `parser` doesn't seem to be initialized). You might consider making an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The process of doing that also might help you find the problem on your own.

Comment: look at `args.date_list`.  Sometimes you also need to look at `sys.argv` to verify if you go the quotes right.

Comment: Why is this tagged bash?

Comment: Did you compare the Python versions on both of your platforms (i.e. `python3 --version`)?

Answer (score 1):

With this script, modified from your sample with added prints:

```
import ast
import argparse
import sys

def parse_args():
    '''Parser for my script '''
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--date_list',type=str, default=None, required=False,
                        help=f"#List of dates to be used. Example for list : [('2017-07-02', '2017-08-15'),('2019-09-02', '2019-11-21')]")      

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

    if args.date_list is not None:
        date_list = ast.literal_eval(args.date_list)
        print(date_list)
        return date_list

print(sys.argv)
parse_args()
```

A couple of sample runs:

```
(base) C:\Users\14256\Downloads>
(base) C:\Users\14256\Downloads>python test.py
['test.py']
Namespace(date_list=None)

(base) C:\Users\14256\Downloads>python test.py --date_list "[('2017-07-02','2020-03-02')]"
['test.py', '--date_list', "[('2017-07-02','2020-03-02')]"]
Namespace(date_list="[('2017-07-02','2020-03-02')]")
[('2017-07-02', '2020-03-02')]
```

This isn't `bash`, but rather Windows with some Anaconda path setup.  But the key things to watch for

- the shell, along with `python` creates a list of strings in `sys.argv`.  We can view, and even parse that directly - no need to use `argparse` is the parsing is straight forward.
- But as defined by the `add_argument`, those strings are assigned to attributes in the `args` namespace.  Strings are not processed.
- Here `args.date_list` processing is up to your code.

`ast` has parsed that string as a list containing one tuple.  That tuple contains two strings.

So the return list could be indexed as `date_list[0][1]` to get the 2nd of those strings.

For a good question, you need to show (and understand) what the `argparse` does and returns.  The error you show, involves code that you do not show: `date_range[LOC_1]`.  I can only guess how that relates to the argparse code.  It looks like `date_range` is a string, since it's the same wording as produced by:

```
 'asstring'[20]
 ''[0]
```